# How to get all metavalue for a specific custom field for all posts in one category?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to get the sum for all the meta values of one custom field. I now get the sum for the metavalues of the whole site. I want it to be restricted to the category you're in.

The code now looks like this:

```
            <?php
            $thevariable = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT SUM($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value)
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta, $wpdb->posts
            WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key='mycustomfield'
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.post_id=$wpdb->posts.id
            "));
            echo '<h1>' . $thevariable . '</h1>';
            ?>
```

Can somebody help me to filter out one category?

Would be amazing!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your WP files, you can add this lines; I guess It will do what you are looking for.

```
 <?php

    $MySum = 0;

    $args = array(
'category_name' => 'MyCategory',
    'meta_key' => 'mycustomfield',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1' );

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args);

    // The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $MySum += get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    endwhile;

    echo '<h1>' . $MySum . '</h1>';
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();


    ?>
```

Comment: the answer sent by pimpin is correct however not a smart one, it will lead to a lot of useless memory loss.
you can achieve the same thing using only one query - query the wp_postmeta table, that's where the custom fields are being saved (use the sum() sql function).